# Key Derivation Function (KDF): Can a key derived from KDF be considered as a secure key?

Tags: cryptanalysis, algorithm-design, keys, key-derivation, pseudo-random-function

Consider a case where we have a master key MS that is used in pseudo-random function to generate a set of pseudo-random values. Then we use key derivation function to derive a key from each of pseudo-random values. Assume all the keys are long enough (in security context).

---

**Question**: In the above scenario can I use the keys derived from the pseudo-random values (or the derived keys) as a encryption key or a key for pseudo-random function?

In other words, is there any situation where we should not consider a derived key as an actual random key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is exactly what KDFs and PRFs are designed for. That is, no *reasonably efficient* attacker will be able to tell if you used an actual random key or something generated from the KDF/PRF. This is of course assuming that your initial seed/master secret was of sufficient entropy, and the way you derive the various values are not done in a silly way.

The practice of deriving many keys from an initial master secret using a KDF is extremely common and you will find it used in almost any standard security protocol like TLS, IPsec or SSH.

> In other words, is there **any** situation where we should not consider a derived key as an actual random key?

Above I only considered security from the perspective of *practice*, i.e., where we assume that the adversary cannot run for an arbitrarily long time. However, in a *theoretical* model where we allow the adversary to run arbitrarily long, there are  many examples where using anything other than a totally random string will break your security. The most common example of course being the [one-time pad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. My question is now, if I have a proper seed (or key) for pseudorandom function. If I use the key and pseudorandom function, can I consider the outputs of the pseudorandom function as the keys? In other words, can I use the output of PRF instead of output of KDF as the proper keys?

Comment: Could you also tell me please, what function I can use for KDF.

Comment: let $f$ be pseudorandom function and $KDF$ be key derivation function. I have a truly random key, $k$. I generate $n$ pseudorandom values: $v_i=f(k,i), 1\leq i \leq n$.  Then I generate $n$ keys: $k_i=KDF(v_i)$. hy cannot I consider $v_i$ as a valid key (in this case I do not need KDF anymore?